Java Android displaying new lines as aspaces
When I set a text in a EditText under Android Java, new lines appear as spaces rather than as actual new lines.
The EditText breaks lines once they are too long, but completely ignores new lines within the String.
Java code:
descField.setSingleLine(false);
  descField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
  descField.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
  descField.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
  descField.setLines(100);
  descField.setMaxLines(100);
  descField.setText("Test of putting \n new lines in \n Android Java \n not working as expected");

xml layout file:
<EditText
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="300sp"
      android:autofillHints="Task Description"
      android:inputType="text|textMultiLine"
      android:scrollHorizontally="false"
      android:lines="100"
      android:ems="15"
      android:textSize="20sp"
      android:id="@+id/editDescription"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:background="@drawable/rounding"
      android:textColor="@color/white"
      android:singleLine="false"
      android:imeOptions="actionDone"
      tools:ignore="LabelFor"

/>
You can see the result here:

Would any of you know how to solve this issue?
I tried replacing \n with \n, \r, and System.lineSeparator(), I even put \n\r.
Nothing works
Dear administrators, you have wrongfully closed my question, the referred question does not contain the solution and does not even refer to a similar problem.
I have found the solution to my problem. Nevertheless, I could not find any similar issue, therefore I suggest you put my question back with the following solution:
The EditText class contains a TransformationMethod, which goal is to take the String provided by the user and transform it in its own way. By default, the TransformationMethod of EditText removes all new lines.  therefore, the following change solves the issues as it removes any TransformationMethod and allows the user to keep his own format:
editText.setTransformationMethod(null);


I think maybe the view does not have enought space to spread the text vertically, can you also share the layout?

@Mirco0 check the original post, I've added the xml code. Nevertheless, I don't  think that is the issue. With very large texts, it works fine and a 10 lines text is not an issue. The line breaks due to the length of text work fine. The EditText just completely ignores the user-written line breaks and treats them as spaces

Have you tried removing tools:ignore: "LabelFor"?

@Mirco0 I did not. But I have just tried and nothing has changed..

While checking the values in the debug, I noticed that the text contains the '\n' line breaks. Nevertheless, there is also a parameter "mtransformed" that contains my String without '\n' characters. Could that be the issue?
